# Windows 10 Start Screen animation choppy on new Dell XPS

Tags: windows-10, dell-xps, start-screen

I just got a brand new, shiny XPS 15
(16GB / i7 / 4k / 512 SSD / Nvidia & Intel GPUS).

Something that annoys me a little bit though is that the start screen animation isn't smooth. It was damn smooth on my old Aspire (circa 2007!) and on this beefed up laptop with 4k screen and Nvidia card, it's choppy.

I know it's a silly thing, but it affects the desktop experience and annoys me. Anyone else have this problem or know a solution? I did change my paging file etc, but it doesn't really make a difference and lowering resolution also doesn't make any difference.

Thoughts appreciated

Comment: What's running in the background at startup?  Anything could be hogging the CPU.

Comment: what are your optimus settings? Does ShellExperienceHost run on nVIDIA or the Intel HD

Comment: It's not just at startup - it's every time and CPU is around 4%.
And I had Nvidia as global, but changed it to automatic and specified ShellExperienceHost to use Nvidia. Still no difference though :-(

Comment: I'm sure performance will be great elsewhere, it's just that I can't understand how my old Intel HD i5 laptop could do it so smoothly - like butter - and this one doesn't. Also notice it slightly when restoring minimized windows - but it happens so quickly I could be wrong.

Comment: what if you change the ShellExperienceHost  to be used by the Intel HD? does this make start smoother?

Comment: Changing it to Intel HD seemed to make a difference actually. Still not as zippy as before, bit a bit smoother and I can live with this I think. Still a bit of a mystery though. But thanks for the thoughts.